# Production filennames Randomizer && js minifier?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, production-environment, minimize

It is not the first time i see it

Ive seen in Facebook source ( and many other sites)

file name like these :

[image]

and Js content like this :

[image]

The `JS` is `minimized` ( whihc I know what is it)

question :

Im sure they aren't tracking these `strange names || minimized Js file`.

How do they do that ?

is there source code which does it automatically ?

*How can I implement these automatically names && auto minimzed ( and hashed named) JS ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume they have a build system which decides the encoded filename based on certain criteria (revision, etc...).  I wouldn't think anyone with a sane mind would do this by hand - it would make maintenance of the site pure agony.

Comment: Eli thats what I asked  , is there any tool / software to do it ...?

Comment: There's any number of ways they could have done it.  I'd say unless you find evidence otherwise, you're probably looking at something done in-house.